# Missing Supporting Files

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that I updated a few video assets for.  The video's where stored in the supporting files folder.  I deleted the old video files and replaced them with the updated videos.  However the old videos are still being played?  Are assets like this copied to some sort of root folder?  If so where is that?

Comment: just clean and build your project again. Also it is better to remove the files from xcode rather than replacing it with another files

Comment: Thank you... Yes I tried doing a clean build.  I just want back to look to see.. I "removed the reference" before then dropped the new assets in.. but now I don't know where the old video actually is to remove it

Comment: please search the old video file name in your project.

Comment: Just tried the "find" and nothing came up.  I named the new files exactly the same as the old ones